# Как обеспечить безопасное взаимодействие JS и HTML разметки

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, безопасность

Есть сервис микроблогинга. Выгружаю из БД посты на страницу и в теге id прячу идентификатор этого поста. Далее клиент нажимает на пост и он отрывается. Запрос идет из JS с помощью AJAX в php скрипт. Из браузера легко подредактировать этот id и можно получить таким образом все посты из БД, или SQL инъекцию сделать или поломать БД неверными запросами.Можно хранить id постов и подобную информацию, где юзер не сможет их посмотреть/изменить?

Comment: это не вопрос взаимодействия разметки и js, это вопрос того что у вас php-скрипт хреновый раз любой клиент может любой айдишник получить или sql-инъекцию сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ID` в любом случае нужен клиенту. И прятать его нет смысла - информация-то не секретная.
И к скули (или другим неприятностям) это никак не относится, нужно на сервере укреплять проверку входных параметров.

Comment: А подскажите, грамотное, по вашему мнение руководство по этому делу.

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov, это огромный пласт по безопасности. И кучу раз описанный в куче книг. Гуглится легко, я же написал что `ID` не нужно прятать.